# Why is ~root null or undefined

Tags: jsrender

I have a JsRender template that I am noticing the expression '~root' is null or undefined. I don't understand why?

Tested for ! ~root and definitely see that is is not defined.

My understanding was that this was a shorthand for the root of the object passed to the template.

Comment: ~root should not be undefined. Can you provide a JSFiddle sample of your issue - or at least provide code of what you are doing?

Comment: I will try to condense it. I just know that unless I put an {{if ~root}} check in the template I get an exception when I try to look at ~root.<property>.

Comment: You have a working example with `{{:~root.address.city}}` here: https://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag (second sample on page).  How does what you are doing compare with this sample?

Comment: Thank you. ~root is null in only some cases. Obviously with this example it is not null. I was wondering based on what I consider the definition of ~root how it can be null I do see some cases where it is. I have just not been able to isolate those cases yet.